# Google Script - Current form selection

Tags: google-apps-script, usb, selection

I have a piece of equipment connected to a computer that is currently controlled with a visual basic script so when you select a particular cell it changes the output value of the equipment.

I want to do the same in a google form script so when you select a certain element in the form it sets the equipment to a value you can then read and type in the box. How do you find out which element in the current form is selected by the user?

Comment: Are you talking about a custom html form? You can do it with a [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). But please provide more details of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am referring to the google application "Google Forms" on the G-Suite platform using "Google Script" does this help?

Comment: For Google Forms you can only retrieve data once the form has been submitted.